# Why is my d3 path not transitioning?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My code looks like the following (omitting the scales that I'm using):

```
// Nesting data attaching "name" as data key.
var dataNest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .entries(data);

// Defining what the transition for the path.
var baseTransition = d3.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear);

// Bind data to SVG (use name as key).
var state = svg2
  .selectAll(".line2")
  .data(dataNest, function(d, i) { return d.key; });

// Enter data join.
state.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line2");

// Set transition and define new path being transition to.
state.transition(baseTransition)
  .style("stroke", "#000")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''); })
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

state.exit().remove();
```

I'm mostly following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/17aa30fd98eb0cc7072f) in which the transitions are working on top of a drop down list. However, while the code I have above displays paths, it does not transition between the paths. Are there any obvious flaws in my approach?

EDIT: I have a more concrete example of what I want to do with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6oqwcoa/12/). I want to transition from `data` to `data2` but the code immediately renders `data2`.

Comment: It seems that you never set the `d` attribute to the enter selection. Also, this question is very hard to answer without a [MCVE].

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry for not providing a more concrete example. I've uploaded some [sample code here](https://jsfiddle.net/h6oqwcoa/12/) that represents essentially what I want to do (transition from displaying `data` to `data2). Any issues you can spot?